# Attributed string loses attributes inside function

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have an attributed string I create like so:

```
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string:  "Father order number:",
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(
                name: "Helvetica Neue",
                size: 18.0)!])

        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.darkGray, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: myMutableString.length-1))

        label1.attributedText = myMutableString
```

This works fine, and the attributes show up on the simulator.  However, when I try to put the attributed string into a function like so, the attributes don't show up when I make the function call.

function call:

```
let myMutableString:NSMutableAttributedString! = getDarkGrayHelveticaAttributedString(str: "Father order number:")
```

function use:

```
label1.attributedText = myMutableString
```

function:

```
func getDarkGrayHelveticaAttributedString(str: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string:  str,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(
            name: "Helvetica Neue",
            size: 18.0)!])

    return myMutableString
}
```

Comment: How are you using the attributed string? Please paste code with usage

Comment: Yes please post the code. Your function looks good to me. You can change to var to let tho

Comment: In your function you've missed NSForegroundColorAttributeName. Add it. Your function works for me.

Comment: I put in the function use case.  oh it's working now.  I forgot to add the color in the function so the text looked the same.